# Maven `<module>` accepting many different relative paths

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

From maven [doc](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-model/maven.html) :

> modules/module* -   List  (Many)  - The modules (sometimes called
>   subprojects) to build as a part of this project. Each module listed is
>   a relative path to the directory containing the module. To be
>   consistent with the way default urls are calculated from parent, it is
>   recommended to have module names match artifact ids.

But my little experimentation shows that it accepts a lot more than mentioned. It accepts `./artifactId` also and `artifactId` also. It even accepts `./artifactId/pom.xml` . Why ?

Has the doc missed the point of mentioning that we can provide relative path till `pom.xml` of that module too ?

Comment: Because they are all the same! Put another way, why do you think it _shouldn't_ accept any of those paths?

Comment: How are they same ? Are you saying pom.xml and artifactId can be used interchangeably ? Also , what's frustrating is doc fails to explain how it resolves the relative path send to it ? My disadvantage is I m not able to find the source code which resolves these paths

Comment: 1) the default POM for a project is `pom.xml` so `xxxx` and `xxxx/pom.xml` are identical. 2) `xxxx` and `./xxxx` are **by definition** identical - that is in the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8089). I really don't understand the question - what of the behaviour do you find confusing?

Comment: Agreed with 2) but not with 1).  What do you mean `xxxx` and `xxxx/pom.xml` is identical ? pom is integral part of a module but **identical** ? The doc clearly mentions -  `Each module listed is a relative path to the directory containing the module`. Either the doc is incomplete to say that we can mention till `pom.xml` also. Because this step is not identical to mentioning path till module.

Comment: I guess the docs are just not completely correct. I would be interested to know if you have a specific application in mind? Something you want "non-standard" module paths for?

Comment: The first thing is: If the documentation misses some parts or might be not 100% accurate please [file in a issue][https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG] and help to improve the docs best would be to offer a patch for the documentation. Apart from that if you think about an URL and say `http://server/path/` and now you address a sub part like `http://server/path/subpart`. This can be written like `http://server/./path/` which in results is identical. ? Maybe I misunderstand a thing here? Can you explain in detail what the real problem is?